# Как зарегистрировать кастомное поле в WordPress для страницы магазина WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть страница `https://titancup.com.ua/shop/`, мне нужно настроить вывод текста после хука `main_content` (сокращение), а если быть точным, то после вывода товаров `http://prntscr.com/jwdlxs`.

Нашел шаблон `arhiv-product.php`, кажется, так называется. Да текст добавляется... но он дублируется для страницы с категорией... То есть используется 1 шаблон...

Не подскажете, как мне решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Шаблон `archive-product.php` срабатывает на главной странице магазина и в категории товаров.

Для того, чтобы распознать, где вы находитесь и вывести соответствующий код, используйте условные теги WooCommerce

```
is_shop()
is_product_category()
```

Шаблон не не надо править на месте - при обновлении WooCommerce ваши правки пропадут. Его надо скопировать в папку

```
/wp-content/themes/моя-тема/woocommerce/archive-product.php и править там.
```